# Can not send udp packet in QT

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, udp

all

I want to use QUdpSocket to send udp packet to get config parameter from specific server,but It failed and I can not capture the sending packet using wireshark.here is my code:

**CGetConfig.cpp:**

```
CGetConfig::CGetConfig(const QString &conf_server,const uint16_t port)
:m_conf_server(conf_server)
,m_port(port)
{
    m_socket = NULL;
}

CGetConfig::~CGetConfig()
{}

void CGetConfig::init()
{

    // create a QUDP socket
    m_socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    m_socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 12345);

    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    m_ip_addr = get_ip_address(m_conf_server);
}

bool CGetConfig::get_reflector(const QString &mac)
{
  qDebug() << "CGetConfig::get_reflector():Entry\n";
  if(m_ip_addr.isEmpty())
  {
    qDebug() << "CGetConfig::get_reflector():ip address of cofnig server could not be resolved\n";
    return 0;
  }

  QString msg("id=1&mac=");
  msg+= mac;
  msg+= "&get_config=fw_type=v.1,cfg_ver=4,set_ver=0,ip=192.168.1.101";
  qDebug() << m_ip_addr;
  qDebug() << m_port;
  qDebug() << msg.toLatin1();
  int count = 0;
  while(count < 3)
  {
     int t = m_socket->writeDatagram(msg.toLatin1(), QHostAddress(m_ip_addr), m_port);

     count++;
 }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
CGetConfig cfg(cfg_server,cfg_port);
cfg.init();
local_mac = "00d033120001";
cfg.get_reflector(local_mac);
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Your code should be work. Have you check return value `t` of `writeDatagram` function? `t` should be  greater than `-1`.

Comment: yes,the return value is ok.the bind function return value is also no problem,it is really wired.I can not see the packet info from wireshark.

Comment: Are you sure you're using wireshark correctly? How about Your destination? If you can access the dest computer, you can see received Bytes easily by using [TcpView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx).

Comment: Just as a general advice, check if your firewall allows outgoing UDP datagrams from port 12345 or whatever port you actually use. On Windows, Wireshark captures outgoing traffic _after_ the firewall.

Comment: I do not think it was a firewall issue,because I tried to use other software to send the same packet,the wireshark capturing is ok.

Comment: by the way,the get_ip_address function behavior can be captured by wireshark.